# Mysterious exception with Python multiprocess

Tags: python, exception, multiprocess

I have a Python 2.6.6 application that uses multiprocess. I'm using a Queue to distribute I/O-heavy work to subprocesses. The application has been running on a x86 machine running CentOS as part of a daily cron job for several months without a problem. I've upgraded the machine to a x64 (it was a linode) and the problems began.

The problem I'm seeing is only part of the work pushed to the Queue gets completed. The program completes. I also see this in the cron output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 242, in _feed
```

Here's the offending code, with line numbers along the LHS:

```
237                         if wacquire is None:
238                             send(obj)
239                         else:
240                             wacquire()
241                             try:
242                                 send(obj)
243                             finally:
244                                 wrelease()
245                 except IndexError:
246                     pass
247         except Exception, e:
248             # Since this runs in a daemon thread the resources it uses
249             # may be become unusable while the process is cleaning up.
250             # We ignore errors which happen after the process has
251             # started to cleanup.
252             try:
253                 if is_exiting():
254                     info('error in queue thread: %s', e)
255                 else:
256                     import traceback
257                     traceback.print_exc()
258             except Exception:
259                 pass
```

So I think the exception is raised on line 242, then printed by the statement on 257. Am I right?

Does anybody know how I can work around this problem?

Comment: Can you include the complete Traceback? You've only got the first line right now.

Comment: That is the complete traceback.

Comment: That's definitely not a complete Traceback. It might be getting truncated somehow in the cron output, but it's going to be pretty much impossible to diagnose the issue without having the rest of it.

Comment: I know that one-line stack traces are unusual, but the _feed method is the target of its own `threading.Thread`. Wouldn't that explain why the stack trace is only one line? Furthermore, I've been trying to reproduce this outside of the cron job, but without success so far - perhaps cron (or the way cron is doing things) is part of the problem here?

Comment: The Traceback you pasted doesn't include what Exception was actually being raised, which should be there even if it was a one-line trace. There's definitely something missing.

Comment: You're right. I'll keep digging.